# How to get the output of java apps in a php web script?

Tags: java, php

I have written a Java application that runs from the command line. I want to allow users to access this via a simple PHP web interface - it'll just allow them to specify certain parameters, and then execute the java app and return the output.

For some reason, I'm getting a 'Permission Denied' error message when I try to do anything with Java, even something as simple as:

```
shell_exec('/usr/bin/java -version 2>&1');
```

returns 'sh: /usr/bin/java: Permission denied ' when run through a browser.

If I give apache a shell account and log in as apache, I can execute this command fine.

Is there some kind of setting preventing the JVM running if there is no associated tty? How can I get this to work? I'm running PHP 5.3.2.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure PHP is running as the Apache user?

Comment: Yes - I just ran 'whoami' in the script and it reported 'apache'.

Comment: safe_mode is off and the error comes from sh, so something executes (this info was on an answer that I deleted, I put it here so it doesn't get lost)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application host may be confined with a tool like [AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) or [SELinux](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux) or [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/) or [SMACK](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/), or similar confinement tools.

It would be very simple to confine an Apache to allow executing `/usr/bin/whoami` but not `/usr/bin/java`.

Ask your system administrator to grant access to java and your jars for you.

Comment: They usually leave a log on unauthorized accesses... in case he's the admin he should look for them

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, SELinux was the problem. I wouldn't have thought of that. Thanks.